# How to delete sequences and procedures during logoff trigger?

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

Could you please help me in a unique situation I am in. I am receiving "ORA-30511: invalid DDL operation in system triggers" when dropping sequences and procedures during logoff trigger.

I need to delete tables, sequences and procedures of users before logoff event happens. I am writing the table details in DB_OBJECTS table upon create using a separate trigger. Below is my logoff trigger - could you please help me where I am doing wrong. Dropping tables is working fine in the below code. Only Dropping sequences and procedures is giving me "ORA-30511: invalid DDL operation in system triggers" error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DELETE_BEFORE_LOGOFF
  BEFORE LOGOFF ON DATABASE
DECLARE
  USER_ID NUMBER := SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SESSIONID');
BEGIN
  FOR O IN (SELECT USER, OBJECT_NAME, OBJECT_TYPE
                FROM DB_OBJECTS WHERE SID = USER_ID
                AND USERNAME = USER AND SYSDATE > CREATED_DTTM) LOOP
          IF O.OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE' THEN
              EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE ' || O.USER || '.' || O.OBJECT_NAME || ' CASCADE CONSTRAINTS';
          ELSIF O.OBJECT_TYPE = 'SEQUENCE' THEN
              EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP SEQUENCE ' || O.USER || '.' || O.OBJECT_NAME;
          ELSIF O.OBJECT_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE' THEN
              EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP PROCEDURE ' || O.USER || '.' || O.OBJECT_NAME;
          END IF;
  END LOOP;
  EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN NULL;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a simple one.

- Error code: ORA-30511
- Description: invalid DDL operation in system triggers
- Cause: An attempt was made to perform an invalid DDL operation in a system trigger. Most DDL operations currently are not supported in system triggers. The only **currently supported DDL** operations are **table operations** and ALTER/COMPILE operations.
- Action: Remove invalid DDL operations in system triggers.

That's why only

> Dropping tables is working fine

succeeded.

Therefore, you can't do that using trigger.

---

You asked (in a comment) how to drop these objects, then. Manually, as far as I can tell. Though, that's quite unusual - what if someone accidentally logs off? You'd drop everything they created. If you use that schema for educational purposes (for example, every student gets their own schema), then you could create a "clean-up" script you'd run once class is over. Something like this:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
   l_user  VARCHAR2 (30) := 'SCOTT';
   l_str   VARCHAR2 (200);
BEGIN
   IF USER = l_user
   THEN
      FOR cur_r IN (SELECT object_name, object_type
                      FROM user_objects
                     WHERE object_name NOT IN ('EMP',
                                               'DEPT',
                                               'BONUS',
                                               'SALGRADE'))
      LOOP
         BEGIN
            l_str :=
                  'drop '
               || cur_r.object_type
               || ' "'
               || cur_r.object_name
               || '"';
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_str);

            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_str;
         EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS
            THEN
               NULL;
         END;
      END LOOP;
   END IF;
END;
/

PURGE RECYCLEBIN;
```

It is far from being perfect; I use it to clean up my `Scott` schema I use to answer questions on various sites so - once it becomes a mess, I run that PL/SQL code several times (because of possible foreign key constraint).

Other option is to keep a `create user` script(s) (along with all `grant` statements) and - once class is over - drop existing user and simply recreate it.

Or, if that user contains some pre-built tables, keep export file (I mean, result of data pump export) and import it after the user is dropped.

There are various options - I don't know whether I managed to guess correctly, but now you have *something* to think about.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. Is there a way we can drop sequences and procedures upon user logoff without triggers?

Comment: You're welcome. I added some more info into the answer; have a look, please.